# What is the best way to implement a mutex over a tree data structure?

Tags: c++, tree, mutex

I am using a tree data structure which looks something like this:

```
class TreeNode
{
public:
    TreeNode() {}

    int addChild(){
        children.push_back(std::make_shared<TreeNode>());
        return children.size() - 1;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> getChild(int i) const{
        return children[i];
    }

    void removeChild(int i){
        children.erase(children.begin() + i);
    }

    std::string getProperty() const{
        return property;
    }

    void setProperty(std::string s){
        property = s;
    }

private:
    std::string property;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeNode>> children;

};
```

I need to implement a locking system, to ensure that the tree works safely in a multi-threaded environment. What is the best way of using mutexes and locks on a tree?

My first approach was to put a `std::mutex` as a member variable in `TreeNode`, and then use `std::lock_guard` around that mutex for each member function. This approach is definitely wrong: one thread can edit a node while another thread simultaneously deletes it in its parent.

My second approach is to put a reference to a `std::mutex` as a member variable. The `std::mutex` itself lives outside of the tree, and thus the whole tree is lock every time any node is edited.

The second approach works, but it also contains some redundancy. Consider the following tree:

```
   A
  / \
 /   \
B     C
```

Accessing A and B at the same time is unsafe, but accessing B and C seems completely safe. Nevertheless, the "lock the whole tree" approach prevents you from simultaneously accessing B and C, leading to a small decrease in efficiency.

My question is: *is there a way of using mutexes on a tree structure so that the tree structure is thread safe but also doesn't contain any redundant locking?* For example, I am wondering if it is possible to lock an entire branch of a tree, leaving other branches open.

I can't think of any simple solutions to this problem, and my gut tells me that the best thing to do is just lock the whole thing (the second approach) and forget about the redundancy. But I would be interested to know if there are other approaches that I should consider.

Comment: You might have less redundancy if you make `TreeNode` methods private and only accessible by the `Tree` - class for managing the whole tree with high level user interface. Then you lock `std::mutex` inside the `Tree` only if some modification is possible. For some read-only operations you don't need to lock.

Comment: A comment to your first approach: If one thread locks a node, it should take temp. ownership before (e.g. using a local `std::shared_ptr<>`). In this case, it's regardless whether another thread removes this node from tree. It will simply live until its unlocked and the temporary `std::shared_ptr<>` goes out of scope. (Of course, the modified node will be destroyed finally in this case but I consider this as least damage...)

Comment: "one thread can edit a node while another thread simultaneously deletes it in its parent."...  That does not matter, as long as you use shared_ptr<> to access individual nodes.  You just need to make sure you always use a copy of the shared ptr in functions that do several operations on a node.

Comment: It seems that we should enforce this: Each node should have its own lock to add and remove children. When a node is locked, then it should not be possible to remove a node which is an ancestor of the locked child node, including the node itself. Therefore, how about acquiring locks on the ancestors and setting children which are not allowed to be deleted for the duration of the lock on the child node, and then relinquishing the locks on the ancestors while doing further work on the child node?